# Close access to folder, but open to files

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I have an apache server where I have folder where asterisk call records are put.
I have a folder with 777 rights and it has records inside it.
Record-names are with random hash so it's hard pick up them. But I need to deny access for site users to this directory. 
I tried chmod 700 to directory and add htaccess with `deny from all` in it. But this doesn't work. I can still go to directory and see all the files.
**UPD1**
Deny from all started working, but records don't work too.
**UPD2**
What's wrong, dudes?
This is a fragment of my conf.file in sites-available

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com>
        php_admin_flag engine on
        Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
</Directory>
```

ExecCGI was before and I decided no to remove it. Why this doesn't work after asterisk restart?

Comment: Is it listing the files?

Comment: Yes. It lists the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^foldername/?$ - [F,L]
```

OR
You  can also use redirectMatch to forbid access to the folder

```
 RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder_name/?$
```

This will return 403 forbidden error for the folder.

Comment: I have some problems, seems that htaccess not working on server. I gonna check it tomorrow and then accept your answer

Comment: @SergeyScopin The reason for my question that you didn't answer is because you may have indexing turned on. If that's the case all you need is `Options -Indexes` to prevent listing.

Comment: @PanamaJack, sorry, I didn't noticed your question. It's .htaccess, right? I found out that this doesn't work at all, because I put random symbols there, restarted apache and site didn't fail. May be I'll use your variant.

Comment: @PanamaJack I used your answer you may answer and I'll acept it.

Answer (score 1):

I think (the question is not clear) that you want to allow anyone who has the full URL to be able to access a file, but prevent them from doing a file-listing in the directory.

The easiest way is probably to create a dummy `index.html` file in your directory (so the webserver delivers that file instead of the the directory contents):

```
$ touch /var/www/domain.com/folder_name/index.html
```

Comment: Good solution. But I think that PanamaJack's solution is more correct.

Comment: define "correctness". a key difference is that my solution requires neither admin access to the webserver nor a working `.htaccess` setup. it is also 16 bytes shorter.